# Apps suddenly can't be opened?

Tags: terminal, safari, security

I had Terminal and TextEdit open, a couple of Finder windows, and possibly another app or two.

This was a few hours after updating to macOS 11.1 (20C69) in case that is the cause.

In Terminal, I did `su - Admin` to change permissions on a directory with sudo.  I forgot to exit before trying to open a new file with TextEdit, so of course I got an error (one account can't open windows in another app's GUI).

Exited Admin and tried again.  Got the **same** error!  Quit TextEdit and re-launched—same error!

Restarted laptop and logged in again.  Now, Terminal and Safari can't be launched (possibly others).  Pop-up appears and vanishes quickly. After several tries, I finally managed to read the first line: "Application (app) interrupted restart."

Switched user to Admin to send this question.  Safari & Terminal both functioning on this account.

In the Admin account, interestingly, when tried to use sudo, I was rejected.  Did `id` and found that that the shell (in Terminal launched by admin account) was running my non-admin account!!! Had to `su` to kill processes (see my answer).

Cause and/or solution?

Answer (score 1):

Still uncertain about cause, but here's one thing that fixed it:

In Terminal, as Admin, I did

```
sudo kill -9 $(ps -ef | egrep -i "(terminal|safari)" | awk '{print $2}' | sort -nr)
```

Then shut down.  After power on again, things seem to be working properly.